# Why getting diffrent result in html5

Tags: html, css

I set my menubar width 1349px and height 100px. But why i am getting different result from other sites like facebook, amazon, stackoverflow etc.
This is HTML code

```
 <nav>
    <div class="topbar">
       <div class="menubar">
           </div>
    </div>
        </nav>
```

This is css

```
.topbar{
    background-color:#ff0000;
    height:100px;
    width:1349px;

}
```

Please check the images
My Code Result
[image: My Code Result]
Other Sites Result
[image: Other Result]

Comment: Use a CSS reset. Try putting this on top `*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}`

Comment: You might also want to investigate into "CSS reset" and "box-sizing"

Comment: The difference is due to presence of scrollbar on Amazon site. Add content to your page unless it gets a page scroll, then you won't notice ~17px gap. and to be correct at that don't give fixed width, give `width:100%;` in CSS. Amazon has given `width:100%`, you have given fixed `width:1349px`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make topbar width 100%. `width:100%`

width 1349px which you are referring in amazone.com is without scrollbar width.scroll bar generaly has around 10px width.

Answer (score 1):

You set your width to a fixed value (1349px in your case) but your browser window is 1366px wide. Work with the following:

```
.topbar{
  background-color: #ff0000;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

You can also avoid the `width: 100%;` because your `div` is a block element which always take the full available width.

Answer (score 0):

You can also opt for `max-width` instead of width to achieve the result you want.

```css
body {
 padding: 0px; margin: 0px;
}
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.topbar{
    background-color:#ff0000;
    height:100px;
    max-width:1449px;

}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="topbar">
       <div class="menubar">
           </div>
    </div>
        </nav>
```

See the image below the width changes with the size of the div or body.
[image]